# Is there a way to sum all values within one year based on as.Date variable

Tags: r

Have a df as:

```
  ID  Status     Created_Date  Booking_Date   Price_Booking
  1   Confirmed  "2013-03-01"  "2013-08-21"   400
  1   Confirmed  "2013-03-01"  "2013-10-01"   350
  2   Confirmed  "2013-04-11"  "2013-10-01"   299
  2   Confirmed  "2013-04-11"  "2013-10-01"   178
  3   Cancelled  "2013-02-21"  "2014-04-01"   99
  4   Confirmed  "2013-08-30"  "2013-10-01"   525
  5   Confirmed  "2014-01-01"  "2014-12-01"   439
  6   Confirmed  "2015-02-22"  "2015-11-18"   200
  6   Confirmed  "2015-07-13"  "2017-04-09"   100
```

Want to calculate revenue per customer within the first year based on Created_Date variable.

I tried:

```
 with(df$ID[df$Status=="Confirmed" & format(as.Date(df$Created_Date), "%Y") == 2013 & format(as.Date(df$Booking_Date), "%Y") == 2013]))
```

Yet, this only calculates the Revenue per calender year, I want to have it relative to the Created_Date

Expected output would be:

```
   ID    Sum_Price_Booking
   1     750
   2     477
   3     NA
   4     525
   5     439
   6     200
```

Comment: Please refrain from using `Rstudio` tag unless the problem is explicitly with that specific IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `group_by` `ID` and `sum` `Price_Booking` values for those values which has difference of less than 1 year  between `Booking_Date` and `Created_Date`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(ends_with("Date")), as.Date) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(Price_Booking[Booking_Date - Created_Date < 365]))

#     ID   sum
#  <int> <int>
#1     1   750
#2     2   477
#3     3     0
#4     4   525
#5     5   439
#6     6   200
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L), 
Status = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
.Label = c("Cancelled", "Confirmed"), class = "factor"), 
Created_Date = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), 
.Label = c("2013-02-21", "2013-03-01", "2013-04-11", "2013-08-30", "2014-01-01", 
"2015-02-22", "2015-07-13"), class = "factor"), Booking_Date = 
structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L), 
.Label = c("2013-08-21", "2013-10-01", "2014-04-01", "2014-12-01", "2015-11-18", 
"2017-04-09"), class = "factor"), Price_Booking = c(400L, 350L, 299L, 178L, 99L, 
525L, 439L,200L, 100L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data.table way in by = you can choose the aggregation

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

    dt <- data.table(
      ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6),
      Status = c(
        'Confirmed',
        'Confirmed',
        'Confirmed',
        'Confirmed',
        'Cancelled',
        'Confirmed',
        'Confirmed',
        'Confirmed',
        'Confirmed'
      ),
      Created_Date = as.Date(
        c(
          "2013-03-01",
          "2013-03-01",
          "2013-04-11",
          "2013-04-11",
          "2013-02-21",
          "2013-08-30",
          "2014-01-01",
          "2015-02-22",
          "2015-07-13"
        )
      ),
      Booking_Date = as.Date(
        c(
          "2013-08-21",
          "2013-10-01",
          "2013-10-01",
          "2013-10-01",
          "2014-04-01",
          "2013-10-01",
          "2014-12-01",
          "2015-11-18",
          "2017-04-09"
        )
      ),
      Price_Booking = c(400,
                        350,
                        299,
                        178,
                        99,
                        525,
                        439,
                        200,
                        100)
    )



    dt[Status == 'Confirmed', .(price_sum = sum(Price_Booking)), by = .(Year = year(Created_Date), ID)]
```